# FileNotFoundException although the text file exist (readable and writable)

Tags: android, exception, text, storage, internals

I am trying to save data into text file in the internal storage and read it again .. It works fine in my mobile with android 11 but when i tried at android 8 it gives me this error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:/data/user/0/com.example.example/test.txt
> (No such file or directory)

It appears at the first time to open the activity but i can clear it - as normal text - and write a new text and save it so the file is there and usable

here is read code

```
    File path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
        File readFrom = new File(path, fileName);
        byte[] content = new byte[(int) readFrom.length()];
        try {
            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(readFrom);
            stream.read(content);
            return new String(content);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
```

and this write code

```
public void writeToFile(String fileName, String content) {
    File path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
    try {
        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(new File(path, fileName));
        writer.write(content.getBytes());
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: getFilesDir() delivers a path that ends on .../files. The file not found message you posted does not contain that files subdir where it should.

Comment: the files folder is there after install the app but the text file only appear after writing on it

Comment: Yoir reaction is not to the point and does not help at all.